# Modelling a collection of name-value pairs in Grails/GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In my Grails app, I have a domain class with a property of type `Map` which will be a collection of name-value pairs (all names and values are strings)

```
class OauthProfile {
    String name
    // other properties omitted
    Map claims
}
```

When I look at the tables generated for this model they look like so:

```
mysql> describe oauth_profile;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version      | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe oauth_profile_claims;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| claims     | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| claims_idx | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| claims_elt | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

A problem with this schema is that at the DB-level there's no relationship between `oauth_profile` and `oauth_profile_claims` which means that it's possible to delete a row in `oauth_profile` without also deleting the associated rows in `oauth_profile_claims`.

Is there a way to model `claims` such that there is an explicit relationship between the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a explicit domain type and do a hasMany <--> belongsTo association like this:

```
class OauthProfile {
    String name
    static hasMany = [claims: OauthProfileClaim]
}

class OauthProfileClaim {
    String name
    String value
    static belongsTo = [oauthProfile: OauthProfile]
}
```

which lets you define your cascase behavior like any other gorm relationship (see [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customCascadeBehaviour)). In the default behavior with a hasMany <--> belongsTo relationship you'll get a `save` `update` `delete` behavior as it says in the [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany):

> The default cascading behaviour is to cascade saves and updates, but not deletes unless a belongsTo is also specified:

Answer (score 0):

I did not try with `Map` field but it works for object. you could use `embedded` property

```
class OauthProfile {
    String name
    // other properties omitted
    Map claims

    static embedded = ['claims'];
}
```

(again, not tested but worth trying)